# Delete Multiple Rows from local json string in JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to delete multiple rows using row ids from local json data in Jqgrid.

Example:

I have ids in Array as below

rowids="1,2";

I want to delete these two rows, 1 and 2, from json string with out using loop.

I am currently using

```
$.each(rowids,function(){
$grid.delRowData(this);
});
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to delete multiple rows with out using looping statements ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the string `"1,2"` is not correct JSON string. Either you have an object `[1,2]` or `[1,2]` or you have a string like `"1,2"`. If you have the string `"1,2"` then you can use `.split(",")` to convert it to array of items which you can enumerate with using `$.each` for example. If you do have a JSON string like `"[1,2]"` then you can use [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) to convert such JSON string to array of items. I would recommend you to use http://jsonlint.org/ to validate which strings as in JSON format and so there can be converted using `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: "1,2" is not the JSON string. It is the id's that i want to delete from grid data.

Comment: You wrote first `ids in Array as below: rowids="1,2";`. In the case you can `$.each(rowids.split(","),function(){...});` instead of `$.each(rowids.split(","),function(){...});`. Then you wrote `1 and 2, from json string` and I wrote that you used wrong terminology: the string `1,2` can't be named as JSON string. Do you tried to use `rowids.split(",")`? Is your problem is solved now?

Comment: I have both JSON String and array. In JSON string I have rows with id 1, 2,3 , etc., . In rowids array  I have 1,2. Now i want to delete rows with id 1 and 2 from JSON string in JQGRID. I dont want to use looping statments. I need to delete it using JQgrid Functions.

Comment: What you mean with "I dont want to use looping statments". It sounds absolutely unserious. Sorry!

Comment: We dont want to use looping statements because there are millions of data thats why we are using Jqgrid and also want to remove data from local JSON string in Jqgrid.

Comment: @SanthoshVijayarangan: You need loop **only over the items of rowids** which needed be deleted. **If you want to send delete request to the server** then deleting of *local* data with respect of `delRowData` will don't help you. You should send delete request to the server, remove the data in the database and refresh the current page of jqGrid.